# ng-repeat doesn't repeat after changing the value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

At first i get the data in the begining but after posting some new students i want the array to update and it updates but table doesn't and i dont know why .It suppose to be like this or what?

This is the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="ang">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
        <title>Angular Practice </title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
        <style>
            div{
                overflow:auto;
                margin:5px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="TableController as bc">
        <div style="margin:5px auto;width:810px">
        <div style="width:250px;float:left;">
        <form name="forma" novalidate ng-submit="forma.$valid&&bc.sendmes()">
        <table class="table table-responsive table-hover">
            <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Add a new Student</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="bc.telebe.name" class="input-sm" required /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Surname</td>
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="bc.telebe.surname" class="input-sm" required /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Age</td>
            <td><input type="number" ng-model="bc.telebe.age" class="input-sm" required /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn-sm" /></th>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
        </div>
        <div style="width:550px;">
            <table ng-controller="TableController as bc" class="table table-responsive table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Surname</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="telebe in bc.telebeler">
                    <td>{{telebe.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{telebe.surname}}</td>
                    <td>{{telebe.age}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is app.js

```
app=angular.module("ang",[ ]);
    app.controller("TableController",function($http){
        var bu = this;
        this.telebe = {}
        bu.telebeler = [ ];
        $http.get("getjson.php").success(function(data){
            bu.telebeler = data;
        });
        this.sendmes=function(){
            $http.post("getjson.php",this.telebe).success(function(data){
                bu.telebeler = data;
                console.log(bu.telebeler);
                bu.telebe = {};
            }); 
        };
});
```

This is the getjson.php and this file is clear no problem with php

```
<?php
    require("config.php");
    header("Content-type:text/json");

    if($s = file_get_contents("php://input")){
        $ar=json_decode($s,true);
        $name = htmlspecialchars($ar['name']);
        $surname = htmlspecialchars($ar['surname']);
        $age = htmlspecialchars($ar['age']);
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO telebe(name,surname,age) VALUES('$name','$surname','$age')");
    };

    $tema = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM telebe");
    $array = array();
    while($sira = mysql_fetch_assoc($tema))$array[]=$sira;
    echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Comment: are you sure you want two table controllers (one in `body`, one in `div`)? I am pretty sure there will be a name collision between them.

Comment: oh i forgot to delete it from table

Comment: Yes that was the issue thanks

Comment: I have added a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `ng-controller="TableController as bc"` directive from the `table` tag. The controller is already defined in `body`.

Currently, you have two controllers with different scopes, each of them sending its own HTTP request to get the initial data. When you are changing the data, only the outer controller is updated but you are reading them from the inner controller. Removing the inner controller will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should insert `$scope` to your controller and define objects for view on the scope rather then on the controller:

```
app.controller("TableController",function($scope, $http){
    $scope.telebe = {};
    $scope.telebeler = [];

    ...
}
```

and then in html you should point to the scope like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="t in telebeler">
```

That should make it work.